Access Kudu CLI via Terraform
Here is my scenario:
I am deploying an Azure Linux Web App, it is a demo environment and the goal is to deploy via Terraform in its entirity - use it for the demo, then destroy it via Terraform (to save on costs as some of the resources are high-end SKUs for various reasons)
In order to complete the deployment of the Web App (which I do not have direct control over) - I normally would need to go to the Kudu CLI shell and run a few commands.
I understand that I can do this via the Kudu REST API, via Powershell or via Azure CLI - but I am not sure how I caqn invoke one of those methods via Terraform.

See following to run executables including PS cmdlets : https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec

Are you still facing the issue. @TheDemonLord


How I can invoke one of those methods via Terraform:

To access and invoke Kudu CLI commands, you can use the
null_resource available in Terraform which mainly focusses on the execution of the script commands post deployment of the resource.
I have taken a sample command and tried executing it once the kudu API URI has been invoked as shown below.
main.tf:
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "xxxx"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "kudurg"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "kudupplan"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "P1v2"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "example" {
  name                = "kudutestap"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_service_plan.example.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.example.id

  site_config {}
}

resource "null_resource" "commands" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      export KUDU_URL="https://${azurerm_linux_web_app.example.name}.scm.azurewebsites.net"
      export TOKEN=$(az account get-access-token --query accessToken -o tsv)
      curl -X POST "$KUDU_URL/api/command" -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
           -d '{"command": "ls"}'
    EOT
  }
  depends_on = [azurerm_linux_web_app.example]
}

Deployment succeeded:

Reference Terraform registry azurerm_linux_web_app.

I will test this later on - that sort-of clarifies some of the things I was missing - if it works (I suspect it will) then I will mark this as the answer - thank you!

Question - are you running that from a Linux command line per chance - I am getting errors, but I think it is because I am running from VSC on Windows

Yes I am running it on the Azure CLI. I would suggest you to use AZ CLI when dealing with the Azure Terraform. @TheDemonLord

I have been testing this - both with Powershell and using the Azure CLI commands - unfortunately - using the above - when I try to run it - I am getting a 403 error

Can you paste the whole error here! @TheDemonLord

Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden)

It means you don't have access to view the web page. Have you logged into CLI before executing the terraform code with az login command. @TheDemonLord

Have you tried it ? @TheDemonLord

Yep - I even ran the code snippets manually (e.g. outside of the Terrafrom deployment) and got the same error.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Thanks heaps for this - Turns out I missed something in the code you wrote - which was causing all my problems :D (didn't apprecate that in the CURL request you had appended /api/command to the URL :D
